# Why is Safari overwriting the text input element value with autofill data?

Tags: html, safari, forms

It seem that Safari 5.1.7 for Windows does not honor the value attribute of text input elements when 'autofill' is enabled for forms. The value that is specified in the HTML input element that should be used as the default when the form is displayed is overwritten by the 'autofill' data Safari has stored.

Is this expected behavior or a known bug? I'd guess so since other browsers I've tested show a different behavior, 'autofill' data is only used when the input elements don't have defaults specified in the value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. You can specify that you wish not to have the input autocomplete by adding a `autocomplete="off"` attribute. This is supported by all major browsers, see [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp).

Comment: I'll give this a go. Thanks. It's just that other browser are behaving differently, even IE ;)